# apply function not changing original value

Tags: r

Related to  question on this page: [Randomly associate elements of two vectors given conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221199/randomly-associate-elements-of-two-vectors-given-conditions)
If I have following data:

```
loss=c(45,10,5,1)

capitals = structure(list(capital = c(100L, 50L, 4L, 25L, 5L), loss = c(5L, 
10L, 10L, 1L, 45L)), .Names = c("capital", "loss"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

capitals
  capital loss
1     100    5
2      50   10
3       4   10
4      25    1
5       5   45
>
```

I am trying to correct any row with loss>capital (assign another random value from vector loss so that loss<=capital) by following command:

```
apply(capitals, 1, function(x){while(x[2]>x[1]) {x[2] = sample(loss,1); print(x[2])} })
```

print function shows that the value is changing in the function but value is not changing in dataframe capitals:

```
apply(capitals, 1, function(x){while(x[2]>x[1]) {x[2] = sample(loss,1); print(x[2])} })
loss 
   5 
loss 
  10 
loss 
  10 
loss 
   1 
loss 
   5 
NULL
> capitals
  capital loss
1     100    5
2      50   10
3       4   10
4      25    1
5       5   45
>
```

Why is value in capitals dataframe not changing and how can this be corrected? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is that a `data.table`?  It looks like one. To use your current code, you would probably want to convert it with `as.data.frame` Some users won't be able to load that data because of the `<...>`

Comment: I have changed to data frame. Thanks

Comment: R functions do not change their arguments. This is true for almost all of them. Use a `for` loop instead of an `apply`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`apply` is evaluating a function, and assignment within functions do not affect the enclosing environment.  A copy is being modified, and that copy is destroyed when the function exits.

Instead, to make use of `apply`, you should build an object, letting `apply` return each element.  Something like this perhaps:

```
capitals$loss <- 
     apply(capitals, 1, 
            function(x){
              while(x[2]>x[1]) 
                x[2] <- sample(loss,1)
              x[2]
           }
     )

capitals
##   capital loss
## 1     100    5
## 2      50   10
## 3       4    1
## 4      25    1
## 5       5    5
```

Here, the new value for `loss` (`x[2]`) is returned from the function, and collected into a vector by `apply`.  This is then used to replace the column in the data frame.

This can be done without the `while` loop, by sampling the desired subset of `loss`.  An `if` is required to determine if sampling is needed:

```
apply(capitals, 1, 
        function(x)
          if (x[2] > x[1]) 
            sample(loss[loss<=x[1]], 1) 
          else 
            x[2]
 )
```

Better yet, instead of using `if`, you can replace only those rows where the condition holds:

```
r <- capitals$capital < capitals$loss
capitals[r, 'loss'] <- 
     sapply(capitals[r,'capital'], 
        function(x) sample(loss[loss<=x], 1)
     )
```

Here, the rows where replacement is needed is represented by `r` and only those rows are modified (this is the same condition present for the `while` in the original, but the order of the elements has been swapped -- thus the change from greater-than to less-than).

The `sapply` expression loops through the values of `capital` for those rows, and returns a single sample from those entries of `loss` that do not exceed the `capital` value.