# Simple 'for' loop works for data.frame but not data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This is related to question on: [Randomly associate elements of two vectors given conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221199/randomly-associate-elements-of-two-vectors-given-conditions/25225735#25225735)

The need is to replace any entry in 'loss' column that is more than 'capital' entry in the same row of 'capitals' data.table. The loss entry has to be sampled from 'loss' vector. 
Following code works when capitals is created as a data.frame but not when it is created as data.table:

```
require(data.table)
capitals<-data.table(capital=c(100,50,25,5))
loss=c(45,10,5,1)

capitals$loss <- sample(loss,replace=F)
capitals
   capital loss
1     100    5
2      50   10
3      25    1
4       5   45


for(i in 1:nrow(capitals)) {
    while(capitals[i,2]>capitals[i,1]){
        capitals[i,2] <- sample(loss, 1)
    }
}
```

It gets stuck here, possibly as an infinite loop. Following code shows that it is stuck in the while loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(capitals)) {
    print("in for loop")
    while(capitals[i,2]>capitals[i,1]){
        capitals[i,2] <- sample(loss, 1)
        print("in while loop")
    }
}
[1] "in for loop"
[1] "in while loop"
[1] "in while loop"
[1] "in while loop"
[1] "in while loop"
[1] "in while loop"
[1] "in while loop"
[1] "in while loop"
[1] "in while loop"
[1] "in while loop"
[1] "in while loop"
...
```

What is the cause and how can it be corrected? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use a `while` inside the `for`? Indeed, this is an infinite loop, because the value of `i` doesn't change inside the `while`. Shouldn't it be `if` instead of `while`?

Comment: Why does the same code work with data.frame? Try replacing first line with this and the whole code works: capitals<-data.frame(capital=c(100,50,25,5))

Comment: Debug your code with [`browser()`, `debug()` or `trace()`](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/debug.shtml). Check why the `while` condition is always true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading it correctly, you want capital>loss.  And, you want to re-sample the ones where that relationship does not hold.  waternova is correct, data.tables behave somewhat differently. I might do something like this in your shoes.
Though, to be honest, I have never written a loop like this.

```
require(data.table)
capitals<-data.table(capital=c(100,50,25,5))
startloss=c(45,10,5,1)

capitals[,loss:=sample(startloss,replace=F)]
##When there are a positive number of rows where capital < loss, that subset gets replaced.
##Previous iteration took a sample of 1, but we want a sample the same size
##as the number of rows where the condition fails, so we use .N, a special 
##variable available in the data table environment that is the number of 
##rows of a subset.
while(nrow(capitals[capital<loss])>0){  
  capitals[capital<loss, loss:=sample(startloss,.N)]
  print(capitals)
}
```

Comment: There is some problem with the code. The loss column of capitals often has values of 4,9,13,19, all of which are not there in 'loss' vector.

Comment: Corrected.  The issue was that "loss" was both a global and a column name.

Answer (score 5):

In R, `data.table` often acts like a data frame, but not when you enter a number in the second argument. `data.table` will treat that number as a function to evaluate, so

```
capitals[1,2] == 2
```

and

```
capitals[1,1] == 1
```

and

```
capitals[1, (2 + 2)] == 4
```

In data.table, columns can be referenced by unquoted column names.

```
capitals[1, loss]
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But what is the proper replacement code for data.table?

Comment: Added to answer. Also, data.tables are very powerful, but with great power comes great responsibility to read at least the intro: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but now it is giving error for this line: capitals[i,loss] = sample(loss, 1) . Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, i, loss, value = 5) :   Attempt to assign to column position greater than ncol(x). Create the column by name, instead. This logic intends to catch (most likely) user errors.

Comment: As far as I can tell you have not expressed in natural language what you expect to be tested and then happen.

Comment: @BondedDust: Question edited above as suggested by you.